# mysql column starts sorting again

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a table with 2000 Entries.
The table sorting has a varchar(100) field called "title_sort" (unicode ut8 ci/ with key)
My problem is that the results returned are not correct.

It sorts A-Z and then starting again at A. (on about row 750)

This seems like a bug to me, here is my query:

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM medias as m 
WHERE 1 
ORDER BY m.title_sort ASC 
LIMIT 1000
```

This returns 763 rows from A-Z then at result 764 it starts again from A.

Comment: You need to post a sample of the actual data. Does the 764th row have leading whitespace?

Comment: Can you provide sample data? Let's say rows 760 to 770 from your query.

Comment: Why do you need `WHERE 1` by the way?

Comment: he is right. 800 rows have a leading whitespace. what a blame... thank you

Comment: i create the query dynamicly. so i have no problems with "and", if i put always "1" after where :-)

Answer (score 1):

you may use this to trim the leading space

```
   SELECT TRIM(LEADING ' ' FROM your_column)
```

or this

```
   TRIM( `col_name` )
```